# Rails 3 with devise undefined method `users_url`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm making some small changes to devise in order to overwrite the layout used and some other things so I decided to create my custom routes with controllers. I only added this to the routes so far:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    :sessions => "sessions/user",
    :registrations => "registrations/user"
}
```

which is supposed to load the login page when accessed by `/users/sign_in` and it does it very well. When I try to ajax post to that url in order to validate the user input and login I get this error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'users_url' for #<Sessions::UserController:0x000000041bed98>):`

The controller is basic and nothing was changed to overwrote devise logic:

```
class Sessions::UserController < Devise::SessionsController
    layout "login" # The only addition. Rest is handled by devise
end
```

I had this working for a good while but today I decided to use devise for another model (admins) and I generated it's files using the devise command `rails generate devise Admin` which completely messed my working code of logging in the users.

Any ideas?